# How to find coordinate to minimise Manhattan distance in linear time?

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to find the point that will minimise the sum of Manhattan distances from a list of points.
so given a list lets say [[x0, y0], [x1, y1] ...] (not sorted) I have to find the point to minimise the manhattan distance from that list of points. I understand the question but am having trouble with how i can complete this in O(n) time.

Comment: Did someone tell you that it is doable in O(n) time ?

Comment: I think you can't do it in O(n) time

Comment: The point you are after is called the *medioid*. In the Euclidean bidimensional space, no linear-time algorithm is known.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What about (median of x-values, median of y-values)?

Comment: @Dave: they don't give the Manhattan-distance-medioid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the median of a list of numbers in linear time.

Taking the x-coordinates and y-coordinates separately, find the median of each. If you need integer coordinates, round half-values to the nearest integer.

The distance minimizing point (DMP) is (median of x-values, median of y-values). There may be multiple DMPs, but this will be one of them.

Why? Well, along either axis, if there are more points in one direction than the other, say p to the left and q to the right, p < q, then moving 1 to the right will increase the distance to p points by 1 and reduce the distance to q points by 1, so reduce the sum of Manhattan distances to points by q-p.

Comment: And use quickselect to find the medians in expected O(n) time.

Comment: The question is in fact unclear. If it is asked to find the point *among the given points*, this solution is not correct.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Granted, though I think this interpretation is likely what was intended given that a linear time solution was requested (and that this was accepted by the OP).

Comment: Mh, is the OP aware ?